# Apps uploaded in appstore connect does not showing in testflight

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm uploading my app on `appstore` connect for running it on `testflight`, but when I visit the appstore connect web site, I'm seeing this.

[image]

It's like its loading but after a few minutes this will happen.

[image]

Like nothing ever uploaded.

Comment: check the email. Your app might get rejected

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed why it should get rejected, I did not submit the app yet, just uploading it.

Comment: If there is a problem with your build then it may be rejected before you even submit it for review; You will get an email telling you what the problem is.

Comment: Did has nothing to do with Flutter. App Store connect takes time to show your builds, they don't show instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Thanks to @Mohammad Ahmed and @Paulw11, I asked the client for emails, I did not have the emails so I could not see whats the problem, and the problem was about using https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler. and I did not read the documentation properly.
I should have remove unused permissions from the final product.